# Участник был удален +4

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, репутация

Сегодня утром встал и появилось оповещение `"Участник был удален" + 4` откуда эти + 4 балла репутации, и причем тут какой-то участник?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: откатились пара минусов, ничего необычного

Comment: Есть ещё небольшая вероятность, что откатился один плюс и семь минусов и более экзотичные комбинации, но пара минусов — самая вероятная гипотеза.

Comment: Там ведь рядом с этим есть ссылка на объяснение, для кого ее сделали...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Удалённый участник поставил тебе 2 минуса. Они отменились.

Или ты ему поставил 4 минуса.

Comment: Жаль, что система не показывает минусы/плюсы к каким вопросам/ответам были отменены.

Comment: значит, если удалится какой-нибудь "старичок", то рухнет вся таблица рейтингов?) Вопрос риторический:) Как-то не правильно это

Comment: @Дмытрык, нет, для удаления высокореповых есть специальный вид удаления.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да хрен бы с ею, таблицей рейтингов... само количество плюсов-минусов меняется. И то, что удаление профиля одного пользователя меняет оценочное качество вопроса либо ответа другого пользователя - вот это и вправду *Как-то не правильно это*.

Comment: @Akina, при удалении высокореповых не меняется.

Comment: @Qwertiy Тут есть ещё вариант "ты ему два минуса, а он тебе один":).

Comment: @Qwertiy меняется или нет, это не зависит от рейтинга практически.